# Python package name in dir(package)

Tags: python, package

I have package `pkg`. In that directory I have `__init__.py` file importing module `aaa`:

**pkg/**init**.py:**

```
import pkg.aaa
```

If I import the package and list its names I see:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> dir(pkg)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__',
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'aaa', 'pkg']
```

So there is `pkg` name present in `pkg's` scope. Is that right? Because few packages I checked does not have that. And I can also do:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> pkg is pkg.pkg.pkg
True
```

And that does not look right.

Comment: Why import pkg.aaa and not import aaa. What you do seems to be a circular reference.

Comment: Because that is what I found in tutorial here: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/. And also if I do just ```import aaa``` I get ```ModuleNotFoundError```.

Comment: Strangely, now it behaves as expected, weird...